# How to declare a table class that contains multi-column primary key?

Tags: sqlalchemy

The columns of the primary key must be in specific order.

I see some code from document :

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'primary_key':[id]
    }
```

But it just does not work (I'm using mysql, and the id primary key will not be generated).
Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

In case columns are declared in the same order as they should be in the primary key:

```
class User(Base):
    field1 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    field2 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Otherwise declare it in `__table_args__`:

```
class User(Base):
    field1 = Column(Integer)
    field2 = Column(Integer)
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint(field2, field1),
        {},
    )
```

Comment: It works. Thx~ BTW, what's the meaning of the example code above?

Comment: @ymfoi ORM configuration doesn't affect table schema. `'primary_key'` in `__mapper_args__` just instructs mapper to use these fields as identity.

Comment: Could this perhaps be extended to include sample `Table` definitions, so it'd make a nice dupe target for Core questions as well. Perhaps the question could be edited to accommodate the change as well.

Comment: As of version 1.4 you don't need quotation marks anymore, e.g.: `PrimaryKeyConstraint(field2, field1),`