# with python sqlalchemy, how do define multiple-column primary key

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am following the tutorial at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html

I see an example for primary key, it seems to use just one column

```
>>> users = Table('users', metadata,
...     Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
...     Column('name', String),
...     Column('fullname', String),
... )
```

how do define primary key with a sequence of columns?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034271/sqlalchemy-orm-how-to-declare-a-table-class-that-contains-multi-column-primary, applicable to Core `Table` pretty much as is, http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.PrimaryKeyConstraint in the official docs.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä yes, it appears to be the case, thanks

Answer (score 4):

try like this:

```
    >>> users = Table('users', metadata,
...     Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
...     Column('name', String, primary_key=True),
...     Column('fullname', String),
... )
```

use `primary_key=True` on any column to primary as key.