# Primary key that is unique over 2 columns in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy I'm a bit confused about composite keys (?), uniqueconstraint, primarykeyconstraint, etc.
How do I create an class that is unique over 2 columns, and refer to that unique combination? Say each `User` is unique by his combination of `name` and `email`:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    name = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
```

Should I use `UniqueConstraint`?:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    name = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint(name, email), )
```

But how do I then refer to a specific user from another class?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034271/sqlalchemy-orm-how-to-declare-a-table-class-that-contains-multi-column-primary Just set `primary_key=True` in both `Column`s.

Comment: Does that make each column by itself unique, or only the combination? The latter is what I am looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlalchemy ORM : how to declare a table class that contains multi-column primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034271/sqlalchemy-orm-how-to-declare-a-table-class-that-contains-multi-column-primary)

Comment: Yes, it creates a composite primary key -- so the combination would have to be unique, but, for example, you can have the same `name` across multiple tuples. Its equivalent to `PRIMARY KEY (name, email)` in a db schema.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the feedback. Turns out adding a `primary_key=True` to each column automatically creates a composite primary key, meaning the combination must be unique but each column individually doesn't have to be unique. So this suffices:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String, primary_key=True)
```